# Remove grep's line number output in Redhat 5.9

Tags: command-line, bash, grep, redhat-enterprise-linux

I havent used RH 5.9 until now. I started with 6 but we have some 5.9 servers. The syntax with 5.9 is a bit different with some things. grep for example will output a number line before  the actual search. Here is an example of that:

```
grep john /etc/shadow
38:john:!$1$/LW9cOmI$.QidFjJmq5xjKfmKugLAy0:16311:0:99999:7:::
```

38 is the line number there. In RH 6, this has been fixed. We are using grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1. Im not the sysadmin so updating grep is unlikely to happen. However, I'd like to know if there is a workaround. I am used to the grep in RH 6. This is a problem because when I do stuff like this, it is actually the wrong field:

```
cat /etc/shadow |grep john | awk -F: '{print $2}'
john
```

When in reality, field 2 should indicate the password field. Is there an option in grep to disable these number lines? I searched and havent found my answer yet. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it's not set up as an alias to `grep -n` which is the normal command to show line numbers? Type `alias` to see if it's listed.

Comment: Try running `\grep john /etc/shadow`. It'll run command without any predefined arguments. If it works try looking at you aliases and remove -n flag from alias from grep.

Comment: I have looked at the aliases and the \grep command and nothing good out of it yet

Comment: What's the output of `alias`?

Comment: Just the ls, ll, vi and which commands, no grep

Comment: How about the output for `which grep`?

Comment: Enter `bash --norc` and try again.

Answer (score 4):

Check the GREP_OPTIONS environment variable.

Set it to nothing just in case then try again:

```
GREP_OPTIONS=''
```